# Trying to reassign a global variable within a following function unsuccessfully (javascript)

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I'm trying to make a basic weather site and I want the user to be able to input the number of days they want displayed. I created a global variable that would hold the number that that user entered. The user clicks submit and the function is called to reassign that variable to the desired number of days. I've checked using console for the value of this variable within the function in charge of reassigning it and it works but when I check the console just outside the function the variable reverts back to its previous value

```html
<script>
           
           var days
            var table = ""
            
           
           function checkValue(){
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
    if (day == 1){
        days = 1;
    }
    else if (day == 2){
        days = 2;
    }
    else if (day == 3){
        days = 3;
    }
    else if (day == 4){
        days = 4;
    }
    else if (day == 5){
        days = 5;
    }
    else{
        alert("Please enter a number (1-5)");
    }
}
         
          console.log(days);
```

the html

```html
<div class = "main">Please enter the day of the week for which you would like the forcast the be displayed (1-5)</div>
        <br>
        <div class="main">
            Enter day here:<br>
            <input id = "day" type = "text" name = "day" value=""><br>
            <br>
            <button id = "submit" name ="button" onClick = "checkValue();" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: `==` sign is used for comparision. Use `=` to assign value to `days`.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM That was a stupid mistake I made after changing things back from before. I corrected it and the variable is still undefined outside the function

Comment: When I click "Run code snippet" it throws an `error, {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 40,
  "colno": 5
}`

Comment: As per the code above, you did not initialize `days` and you did not call the function `checkValue` above in your code, and so the `console.log` will display `undefined`.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM Sorry the function is actually called by the button in the html code. I'll include the html code aswell

Comment: @PhaniKumarM also if I initialize the variable to 0 at the beginning, the value of the variable will be correct within the function but will be reset to 0 when leaving the function

Answer (score 0):

Try following code if you want to keep max day as 5 you can put max = "5" as I placed min = "0"

```js
(function() {
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
      myNode()
    };
    
   // alert(day);
    
    function myNode(){
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
    console.log(day);
    if (day == 1){
        day == 1;
    }
    else if (day == 2){
        day == 2;
    }
    else if (day == 3){
        day == 3;
    }
    else if (day == 4){
        day == 4;
    }
    else if (day == 5){
        day == 5;
    }
    else{
        alert("Please enter a number (1-5)");
    }

 



}

})();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="day" min="1">
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```